# Qt while loop not working as expected

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a while loop and based on flag loop will terminate, but even after making the flag true loop is not exiting.

In debug mode its working fine and in release mode with qDebug also its working. How to trace this problem

```
while (1)
{
    if(isFlagUpdated)
    {
        isFlagUpdated = false;
        break;
    }
    qDebug()<<"Running while loop";
}
```

If I remove `qDebug()<<"Running while loop";` its not working in release mode

Comment: Is this multi threaded?  Also, you could put a `qDebug()<<"In if(isFlagUpdated)";` to see if you truly enter the if.

Comment: What is the full type of the `isFlagUpdated` variable? Any `volatile`, `atomic`, ...? Otherwise the compiler is free to not re-read it.

Comment: More info ar e needed. Try to come up with a minimal compilable  example     that show the problem.

Comment: Can't see how this issue is related to Qt...

Comment: Yes the while loop is inside thread

Comment: I already put QDebug statment inside "if(isFlagUpdated)" but its not entering and flag is getting true in the slot

Comment: isFlagUpdated is just a bool variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler may detect that "isFlagUpdated" isn't supposed to change, and optimize your code.

You may want to declare "isFlagUpdated" as volatile to avoid this behaviour.

Comment: If the flag is being set from another thread, consider using [std::atomic_bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use your flag in the loop condition?

This loop will run until isFlagUpdated gets true.

```
While(!isFlagUpdated) {
    qDebug() << "Running while loop";
}
```